# Replacing CMOS SRAM with NV SRAM

Tags: integrated-circuit, cmos, sram, non-volatile-memory

I have an electronic board from a professional video device containing a 256K 8bit CMOS SRAM 28 pin DIP. I wish to replace this memory with a Nonvolatile 256K 8bit RAM 28 pin DIP, so that I can read and write the data structures with my eprom programmer which is the popular TL866II.

I know for sure that this board can support the Sony CXK58257AP-10 and the Sanyo LC35256D-10LL. The access time is 100ns.

My eprom programmer supports these NVRAM same size:
ST Microelectronics M48T35AY M48T35AV M48Z35Y M48Z35AY M48Z35V M48Z35AV
Dallas DS1230AB DS1230W DS1230Y
Texas Instruments BQ4014YMA BQ4014LYMA

The pinout of these NVRAM seem to be the same of that of the two SRAM above (please double check). Which of them is truly compatible?

What features I have to check in the datasheet to choose the right one?

Comment: SRAM is orders of magnitude faster than NVRAM - without a way to determine access speed, replaceability is undeterminable.

Comment: Thanks, the required access time is 100ns. (question edited)

Comment: What's the purpose - debugging? reverse engineering? If you reboot the device, the software on the device probably won't know that it's already got valid data in RAM. It will still do a full reboot, so it won't save your settings.

Comment: The purpose is reverse engineering. The current SRAM on the board has a battery for data retention. When the device boots, if the memory has no data it creates new structures to save settings. The problem is that these settings in this device are critical. I'm not going too much into detail. I just need to understand these data structures and to modify them from the memory once they have been written.

Comment: I used SRAM CY62256LL-70 and DS1230Y-70 in the same NEC V25 board, no problems.

Comment: As well as this idea do also consider the idea of making a rig to read out the memory from the SRAM chip while the power is still attached. One idea or the other might turn out to be easier. I would suggest doing this with the TL866II, if it supports the SRAM chip, but it probably doesn't and apparently it has not been reverse-engineered to make it possible to add support for more chip types.

Comment: TL866II supports a few SRAM, but just to test their logic, no read or write. The only option is to use a NVRAM, but which one?